# How can I make uWSGI listen to another machine?

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, tcp, nginx, uwsgi

I have two machines on the same LAN, machine A runs nginx and machine B runs uWSGI. I want nginx to communicate with uWSGI by TCP port 1717.

(Ideally, I'd like to do it using the `service uwsgi start` command so I can profit from the upstart script that's built in Ubuntu. I wouldn't mind editing that script but after looking at it I don't think it's the right thing to do!)

I tried running `sudo uwsgi start --uwsgi-socket 127.0.0.1:1717` but it wouldn't work and nginx logs would show the following error (data in bracket sanitized):

```
2012/05/29 00:06:46 [error] 19608#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: {public ip}, server: {domain}, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://{machine B's IP}:1717", host: "{domain}"
```

Clearly this way isn't working. I don't know enough about uwsgi to fix this by myself, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
socket = address:1717
```

in the uwsgi configuration of your app

Comment: What address should I use? uwsgi machine, nginx machine, localhost or 0.0.0.0?

Comment: the address of the uwsgi machine